# How to check if element is visible in Zepto

Tags: javascript, zepto

[Zepto](http://zeptojs.com/) does not support [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)'s `.is(':visible')` technique.

So how do you check if an element is visible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've never used Zepto, but:

```
.css('display') !== 'none'
```

would probably work. [Here's a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/9a6pQ/)

Comment: The question doesn't ask whether the element is not hidden. What if the element is set to `visibility:hidden`?

Comment: @minitech Nice/thanks—I figured would be it. I wasn't sure if Zepto had another way built in. Bonzo ( https://github.com/ded/bonzo ) basically does something like that too if you look at the source of its `.toggle()` method. It checks native `el.style.display !== 'none'` and the whether there is a width or height.

Comment: @Jamie "Elements with `visibility: hidden` or `opacity: 0` are considered visible, since they still consume space in the layout" according to http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Answer (score 2):

Zepto has some official extensions. You can include **selector** module to enable  `.is(':hidden')`

- [The selector module](https://github.com/madrobby/zepto/blob/master/src/selector.js#files)
- [List of modules can be found here](http://zeptojs.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too familiar with Zepto, however I would imagine you could just use basic JavaScript to do some form of detection:

```
function isVis(ele) {
    if(ele.css('display')!='none' && ele.css('visibility')!='hidden' && ele.height()>0) {
        return(true);
    } else {
        return(false);
    }
}
```

Then in use:

```
var div=$('#div_id');
if(isVis(div)) {
    // Element is visible
} else {
    // Element in not visible
}
```

Comment: Note that `block` isn't the only possible visible `display` type. There's `inline`, `inline-block`, `table`, `table-row`, `table-cell`... you get the picture.

Comment: @minitech is right about the display types. As a hack, I think this is probably the best solution

Answer (score -1):

How about

```
.css('display') === 'block'
```

or, as minitech suggested:

```
.css('display') !== 'hidden'
```

If you *really* need to use these pseudo-selectors, you can always [implement them manually](https://gist.github.com/2324454).

Comment: Zepto does not support `:hidden`.

Comment: Invisible elements have `display=none` not `display=hidden`